# XFCE keyboard shortcut with ~ or $HOME equivalent

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I would like to set a keyboard shortcut in linux Mint xfce with home path in command.

Example: Use CTR + ALT + n to launch:

x-terminal-emulator -e '/usr/bin/nvim ~/my_doc.txt'

But ~ is never replaced with my home path.

Any idea?

Kind regards.

XFCE: 4.18.1
Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia

I tried $HOME without success.